# react native context state becomes undefined when navigated to a screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using react-navigation v6 and context api, when I navigate from my component to a screen, the context state `image` which even though wraps my component, becomes `undefined`. Below is the code flow and relevant code from my components & screens.

`EXPECTED OUTPUT` -> `image` context state should persist (as I'm using context provider)
`ACTUAL OUTPUT` -> `image` context state becomes undefined when I navigate to different screen.

**AppStack**

```js
const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name={'AppDrawer'} component={AppDrawer} />
      <Stack.Screen name={'StoreStack'} component={StoreStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>

  )
}
```

**AppDrawer**

```js
const AppDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name={'AppBotTab'} component={AppBotTab} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}
```

**AppBotTab**

```js
const BotTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppBotTab = () => {
  return (
    <BotTab.Navigator>
      <BotTab.Screen name='CameraPreview' component={CameraPreview} />
      //... other screens
    </BotTab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

**CameraPreview** -> The Culprit (seems like)

```js
const CameraPreview = ({ navigation }) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const cameraRef = React.useRef<ExpoCamera>(null);
  const [isCameraReady, setIsCameraReady] = useState(false);
  const [cameraType, setCameraType] = useState(CameraType.back);

  return (
        isFocused && (
            <Camera
                cameraRef={cameraRef}
                cameraType={cameraType}
                flashMode={flashMode}
                onCameraReady={() => setIsCameraReady(true)}>
                  <MediaContextProvider>
                    <CameraControls
                      isCameraReady={isCameraReady}
                      onToggleCamera={toggleCamera}
                      setFlashMode={setFlashMode}
                      cameraRef={cameraRef}
                      onDismiss={() => navigation?.goBack()}
                    />
                  </MediaContextProvider>
            </Camera>
        )
    );
}
```

**CameraControls**

```js
const CameraControls = () => {
  const { image, setImageAndUpdateSize } = useMedia();
  const [cameraState, setCameraState] = useState('PREVIEW');
  
  useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Mounting CAMERA CONTROLS');
        return () => {
            console.log('image: ', image); // undefined
            console.log('Umnounting CAMERA CONTROLS'); // gets called when navigating to StoreStack screen
        };
  }, []);

  const takePhoto = async () => {
        if (cameraRef.current) {
            const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(CAMERA_OPTIONS);
            const source = data.uri;
            if (source) {
                setImageAndUpdateSize({ path: source })
                cameraRef.current.pausePreview();
                setCameraState('IMAGE_PREVIEW');
            }
        }
  };

  switch (cameraState) {
        case 'PREVIEW':
            return <CameraPreviewControls onTakePhoto={takePhoto} />;
        case 'IMAGE_PREVIEW':
            if (!image?.path) return null;
            return <PhotoPreview imageURI={image?.path} />;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

**PhotoPreview**

```js
const PhotoPreview = ({ imageURI }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Mounting PHOTO REVIEW');
        return () => {
            console.log('Umnounting PHOTO PREVIEW'); // gets called when navigating to StoreStack screen
        };
  }, []);

  return (
    <ImageBackground source={{uri:imageURI}} />
    //... other components
    <FiltersPanel />
  )
}
```

**FiltersPanel**

```js
const FiltersPanel = () => {
  ...
  return (
    //...
    <Gifts />
  )
}
```

**Gifts Component**

```js
const Gifts = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const goToStore = () => {
      navigation.navigate('StoreStack', {
          screen: StoreStackPages.StoreScreen,
      });
  };

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={goToStore}>
            <Image source={GIFT} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.image} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

**MediaContext**

```js
const MediaContext = createContext({
  // other default values
  setImage: () => {},
});

const MediaContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState<Partial<PickerImage>>();
  // other states
  return (
    <MediaContextProvider value={{image, setImage}}></MediaContextProvider>
  )
}

export const useMedia = () => {
  const context = useContext(MediaContext);
  const setImageAndUpdateSize = (capturedImage) => {
    const {setImage} = context;
    return setImage(capturedImage);
  }

  return {
    ...context,
    // other functions & utilities
    setImageAndUpdateSize
  }
}
```

This is the whole flow. So, again, the problem is, in simple words, **when I capture a photo in `CameraPreviewControls`, the `image` is set successfully and as the `cameraState` now changes to 'IMAGE_PREVIEW', the `PhotoPreview` component gets mounted, and I can see the `ImageBackground` loaded with my context `image`, now when I tap the `GIFT` icon (being in the `PhotoPreview` component), I navigate to `StoreStack`, BUT NOW when I go back from StoreStack, the context `image` changes to `undefined` and the `cameraState` changes to `PREVIEW`** which shouldn't be the case as I'm still wrapped under `MediaContextProvider` so the `image` context state shouldn't be `undefined` and also when I navigate to StoreStack and comes, the `CameraControls` and `PhotoPreview` component gets un-mounted which also shouldn't be the case in react navigation, as according to react-navigation docs, when we navigate to a screen, the previous screen does not get un-mounted.

Can someone shed some light on this, it would be really helpful!!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useIsFocused is triggering a rerender when you navigate away. When you come back the context is rerendered. useIsFocused can be removed to stop the rerender when navigating away.